# I can't get my Android program to run correctly on an AVM in Eclipse

Tags: android

This is a simple question about getting started with developing Android apps using Eclipse.  I have followed all the tutorials on the developer site for installing Eclipse, the SDK and the ADT plugin.  When trying to run a simple Hello World program, everything seems to compile correctly, but then the virtual machine comes up empty.  In the Console Window it reads:

The program then just sits and my text never comes up.  Any idea with what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Give some time to emulator to load it. Actually it takes ages. Anyway in mean time you can switch to DDMS perspective and and check the LogCat view. Basically it displays all messages from emulated android system. I bet it will be very busy ;-)
So, don't panic, wait a bit :-) It happens to me too.